# Open Facebook share in native Facebook app on mobiles

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm aware that this question has been asked a couple of times now, however even after researching, I still can't figure out what my next steps could be:

**Goal:** To open a Facebook share link (button) on a simple website (PHP…) through the native Facebook app on mobiles instead of opening a new browser window. I don't want to share the whole website but rather a specific sub-site (www.example.com/apples or www.example.com/pears).

**Problem:** The click on the share link opens a new site with the according Facebook log-in form instead of opening the native Facebook app.

I researched the iPhone URL Schemes but didn't find a possibility to share a website, only to open the main website's Facebook profile page, if existing. In my case, a specific profile page of the website will not exist. http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

On desktop computers I'm invoking the share dialog by using a popup with a simple `window.open` function…

For now I'm trying in iOS and Facebook. Later I will try to do the same with twitter.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: still no answer pfff